# Can we call two procedures using a single job

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, jobs

I need to call two procedures using single `oracle job(dbms_scheduler.create_job)`

I have following code:

```
BEGIN 
  dbms_scheduler.create_job ( 
    job_name => 'test_JOB', 
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
    JOB_ACTION => 'UP_TRYNR;',
    start_date =>sysdate, 
    enabled => true, 
  ); 
END;
```

Here I'm running `UP_TRYNR`, I want to run another procedure along with `UP_TRYNR` and i don't want to call that anther procedure in `UP_TRYNR` procedure.

What should I do?

Comment: You want to execute the PROC1 and then PROC2 sequentially? Or both at same time?

Comment: Both PROC1 and PROC2 at the same time..

Answer (score 4):

`JOB_ACTION` is an anonymous PL/SQL block, so you can do something like this:

```
BEGIN 
   dbms_scheduler.create_job ( 
    job_name => 'test_JOB', 
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK', 
    JOB_ACTION => 'BEGIN UP_TRYNR; YOUR_SECOND_PROCEDURE; END;',
    start_date =>sysdate, 
    enabled => true, 
   ); 
END;
```

By the way, you should probably add `repeat_interval` to your `create_job`.

Comment: I tried your mentioned answer but seems like it will first call 'BEGIN UP_TRYNR'. After 'BEGIN UP_TRYNR' is completed it will call 'YOUR_SECOND_PROCEDURE'. I wanted to call them together.

Comment: Check this out: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4712493580500